# Why do I get an `IncompatibleProtocolError` when trying to connect to RabbitMQ from another container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am building a docker-compose file. I start a RabbitMQ container and bind the necessary ports to host. Then I'm trying to connect to it from another container.

Thus, I set the `network_mode` option to `host` as shown below, so I can use `localhost` as the queue's hostname. Below you can see the docker-compose yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  queue:
    image: "rabbitmq:3"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
  worker:
    image: "some_image"
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on: 
      - queue
```

When I run the code, the worker tries to connect to RabbitMQ with hostname `localhost` and I get an `IncompatibleProtocolError: StreamLostError: ('Transport indicated EOF',)` error. Specifically:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
recommender_filtering_worker_1  |     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
recommender_filtering_worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
recommender_filtering_worker_1  |     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
recommender_filtering_worker_1  | pika.exceptions.IncompatibleProtocolError: StreamLostError: ('Transport indicated EOF',)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: localhost will not work try to use `queue`

Comment: @LinPy but why? Since I have set `network_mode: "host"`? `queue` does not work also. Gives back a `pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError` even without the `network_mode: "host"`.

Comment: Sorry did not see that under the worker. You are right

Comment: did you try to start the queue and the worker separately? I think your app is not waiting for the queue to be ready. The "depends_on" grants only that the queue container starts before the worker but it doesn't grant its status

Comment: @Stefano tried it with the queue already up. It worked, so that seems to be the problem. Now I have to figure out how to delay the second container until the queue is up.

Comment: if you don't mind I'm going to add a solution then since the issue is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your app does not wait for the queue to be "ready" to accept connections. The `depends_on` block makes sure that your queue container starts before the worker but it does not grant that your queue will be ready to accept connections.

There are different solutions that can be adopted here. Keep hitting the queue until it answers (not constantly but every 10-15 seconds maybe) or add a "wait_for" script (https://github.com/eficode/wait-for).

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using **healthchecks** in docker-compose itself, without additional scripts.
Command for checking connection ready: *nc -z localhost:5672* .

Example of *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - ./rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq
        - ./rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z localhost:5672

  worker:
    build: ./worker
    command: python ./worker.py
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
        rabbitmq:
          condition: service_healthy
```